# Get all occurrences between closest double brackets

Tags: php, regex

Given string `$str = 'aa {{asd}} bla {{{888 999}} {555} 777 uiii {{-i {{qw{er}}';`

Need get all occurrences between closest opening-closing double curly brackets.

**Desirable result:**

- asd
- 888 999
- qw{er

If try: `preg_match_all('#\{\{(.*?)\}\}#', $str, $matches);`

**Current output:**

- asd
- {888 999
- -i {{qw{er

though, these occurrences  aren't between *closest* double curly brackets.

Question is: what is appropriate pattern for this?

Comment: What would the expected output be if the input contains something like `{{{a}b}}`? `{a}b` or `a}b`?

Comment: @Rawing  - In this case  expected output: `a}b`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
\{\{(?!\{)((?:(?!\{\{).)*?)\}\}
```

The trick here is to use a negative lookahead like `(?!\{\{)` to avoid matching nested brackets.

---

```
\{\{       # match {{
(?!\{)     # assert the next character isn't another {
(
    (?:    # as few times as necessary...
        (?!\{\{).  # match the next character as long as there is no {{
    )*?
)
\}\}       # match }}
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/MBgnlQ/1)

**Regex:**    `(?<=\{{2})(?!\{)[\s\w\{]+(?=\}\})`

`(?=\}\})` Should contain double curly braces ahead

`(?<=\{{2})` Should contain curly braces behind

`(?!\{)` should not contain curly braces one curly brace behind two matched

**PHP code:**

```
$str = 'aa {{asd}} bla {{{888 999}} {555} 777 uiii {{-i {{qw{er}}';
preg_match_all("/(?<=\{{2})(?!\{)[\s\w\{]+(?=\}\})/",$str,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => asd
            [1] => 888 999
            [2] => qw{er
        )

)
```